# Estimating GuardDuty costs by pulling VPC flow logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to estimate how much GuardDuty is going to cost me per month and according to https://aws.amazon.com/guardduty/pricing/ I should look at how many cloudtrail logs I produce a month as well as how much VPC logs in GB I produce a month.

Using boto3 S3 I can count how many logs are in my bucket, which tells me how much I am going to spend having GuardDuty read my logs. Now I wish to find how many GB's of data my VPC logs are producing, but I can't seem to figure out where I can pull that kind of information from. I want to programmatically see how many GB's of VPC flow logs I produce a month to best estimate how much I would spend on GD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet is to show how to get the size of VPC flow flogs associated with each network interface in the VPC. You have to modify the script to get the logs for the entire month and sum it.

```
import boto3

logs = boto3.client('logs')

# List the log groups and identify the VPC flow log group
for log in logs.describe_log_groups()['logGroups']:
  print log['logGroupName']

# Get the logstreams in 'vpc-flow-logs'
for log in logs.describe_log_streams(logGroupName='vpc-flow-logs')['logStreams']:
  print log['logStreamName'], log['storedBytes']
```

[describe_log_streams](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_streams)

> Lists the log streams for the specified log group. You can list all
>   the log streams or filter the results by prefix. You can also control
>   how the results are ordered.
>
> **This operation has a limit of five transactions per second, after which transactions are throttled.**

Request Syntax

```
response = client.describe_log_streams(
    logGroupName='string',
    logStreamNamePrefix='string',
    orderBy='LogStreamName'|'LastEventTime',
    descending=True|False,
    nextToken='string',
    limit=123
)
```